# How to change <select> value based on in-line style?

Tags: jquery, html-select

Hi want to change  values on behalf of inlne css like is i set in div `<div style = "font-family:arial"></div>` so `<select>` value will show first option selected if i set in div `<div style = "font-family:quicksandregular"></div>` so `<select>` value will show third option selected

I am confused that how to get this using jQuery all this happens on run time. My code is mentioned below or you can check the [**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qE8Z9/)

**HTML**

```
<select name="select" id="editorFontN">
    <option value="arial">font 1</option>
    <option value="alex_brushregular">font 2</option>
    <option value="quicksandregular">font 3</option>
</select>
<div style="font-family:quicksandregular"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var Default = $('div').css('font-family')
var sele = $('#editorFontN')

if ($('div').css('font-family') == arial) {
    sele[0]
} else if ($('div').css('font-family') == alex_brushregular) {
    sele[1]
} else if ($('div').css('font-family') == quicksandregular) {
    sele[2]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var Default = $('div').css('font-family')
var sele = $('#editorFontN')

sele.val($('div').css('font-family'))
```

Comment: thanks for help @Arun P Johny but i dont want to change name like Font 1, Font 2, Fotn 3

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/qE8Z9/2/)

```
sele.val($('div').css('font-family'));
```

Comment: + 1 for the ; at the end

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qE8Z9/6/)**

Try this

```
 var Default = $('div').css('font-family')
var sele = $('#editorFontN');
if ($('div').css('font-family') == "arial") {

    sele.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

} else if ($('div').css('font-family') == "alex_brushregular") {
    sele.prop('selectedIndex', 1);

} else if ($('div').css('font-family') == "quicksandregular") {

    sele.prop('selectedIndex', 2);

}
```

Hope this helps,Thank you